# Only replacing parts of text after specific word

Tags: javascript, sed

We are trying to make some filenames consistent in a large-ish javascript codebase. We want to camel case all the file names, but we also need to camel case the "require" statements.

So any arbitrary require statement should be changed like this:

```
// before
var PurchaseProgressBar = require('src/js/Shared/modules/ProgressBar');
// after - camel cased each part of the path
var PurchaseProgressBar = require('src/js/shared/modules/progressBar');
```

So far we have a sed script that *almost* works:

```
sed -e "/require/ s=\b\(.\)=\l\1=g"
```

But what this produces is:

```
//  "var PurchaseProgressBar" was also changed! but shouldn't be
var purchaseProgressBar = require('src/js/shared/modules/progressBar');
```

How do we make this sed script (or some other approach) only camelcase the text inside the require calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every letter you want to change follows a / (ie no require path starts with Src or something) then that can differentiate the parts of the line you want to change:

```
sed -e "/require/ s=\/\b\(.\)=/\l\1=g"
```

This works for me on your sample input.

I just tried a variation to allow for a single quote instead of the slash in the pattern.  This works if the original contained "require('Src/js/Shared/modules/ProgressBar')"

```
sed -e "/require/ s=\(['\/]\)\b\(.\)=\1\l\2=g"
```